# Were warhorses unable to graze in grass fields and thus needed to be manually fed an exclusive type of hay?

Tags: military, middle-ages, cavalry

I found this trivia in a historical strategy game (whose name shall not be disclosed) and I want to know its credibility.

It is stated that warhorses — say, destriers or other types of European warhorse used by knights or heavy cavalry — can't graze naturally on grass fields because they got used to eating their exclusive type of hay — I don't know the name of this type of horse food. Hence, the cavalry or the supply units also had to bring this horse food, too.

So, is this generally true? If so, what are specific examples of this happening?

Comment: Might be just me, but I'm struggling to picture a band of knights traveling around with a bunch of carts loaded with hay in the rear for the sole purpose of feeding their steeds. Methinks it's just some game mechanics to offset some otherwise advantageous characteristics of using a war horse in your strategy game.

Comment: I believe this overstates the truth.  Warhorses can eat grass, but they need more energy than grass can provide.  Left to graze, they'll starve because they burn more calories than they can consume. Warhorses' diet needs to be supplemented with grain. (hat tip to @jamesqf for the correction).

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: No, or at least it varies depending on the type of hay.  Grass hay is just dried grass, alfalfa hay has more energy and tends to make a horse "hot" (though I don't know when alfalfa started to be used for hay).  The horses might also get a supplementary ration of grains for energy, but they'd also need hay/grass for bulk.

Comment: As I remember, the ponies of Plains Indian tribes fed on grasses and could graze anywhere on the plains.  The horses and mules of the US army were fed on grain which had to be brought along in wagons pulled by mules which needed more grain to feed, so the Indians weer more mobile than the army.  But in winter the Indian ponies couldn't graze much and were hungry and weak, limiting Indian mobility, while the cavalry could still move fast and strike the Indians.

Comment: As an aside, this also ignores the (brutal) fact that an army on the move would commandeer supplies from local residents, friend or foe, just as they would for the men.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: Ah, yes.  I've been known to suffer from occasional caffeine deficiency myself.

Comment: Anyone who has spent any length of time around horses in the field will tell you they never refuse the chance to browse on available grasses.

Comment: @Matt Balent: Not just grasses, either.  Mine loves to snack on bitterbrush (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purshia_tridentata ), and will eat any of a number of plants other than grass growing in meadows.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace offering to muck out the stables for a week should be decent penance

Comment: [The answer to "*How did Ghenghis Khan's army feed so many horses?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10330/how-did-genghis-khans-army-feed-so-many-horses/10342#10342) provides a rough calculation for feed requirements of a cavalry army. This can easily be adapted to both other landscapes and horse breeds.

Comment: @MAGolding: Grain feed for horses must be strictly limited, and the bulk of the feed must remain hay or forage, else the horses will rapidly develop digestion problems. [The Rules for Feeding Your Horse](https://www.humanesociety.org/resources/rules-feeding-your-horse)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy, you gotta have supply carts for you marching army anyways. Why not get bunch of cart with horse food too?

Comment: @user28434: Because hay is bulky, especially before the invention of modern balers.  Even baled hay, which is tightly compressed (a bale is roughly 18" square, 4 ft long, and weighs ~100 lbs) takes a lot of space.  A good-sized horse (16 hands or so) will eat about a bale a week (plus some grain &c).  Loose hay?  You'd need a lot of carts to haul it,  which means you need lots of horses to pull the carts, which means you need more carts to haul the hay for those horses...

Comment: Unleaded hay only !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. War horses are simply horses. Perhaps a little bit finicky with eating but not overly so.

The reason why they were fed hay is different. You need a **LOT** of fields with *edible* grass to daily feed them. Those pastures have to be guarded, lest the horses run away or the enemy runs away with your horses. Grass must be ready for consumption and for some parts of the year it isn't.

It's logistically much easier to feed the horses hay while on campaign. Yes, you need to bring that hay to the encampments. But you don't have to guard the pastures. And part of the year you have to bring your hay anyway.

Comment: Before the introduction of modern balers, I would think it'd be quite difficult to transport enough hay to feed horses.  Even today, I certainly wouldn't take hay along on a horse-packing trip.  Horses could easily be hobbled or picketed to graze.  They are herd animals, and tend to stay with a group unless frightened.  Even then, they'll usually return.  (If I had room, I'd tell you about my friend's horse and the charging bear...)

Comment: @jamesqf it's as much or more the quantity of feed needed for a large group than the problem guarding the horses. A large mounted force can easily need more land to pasture their horses than is available in a campaign area (and guarding dozens of acres of land 24/7 is going to drain your foot troops).

Comment: I would assume the group would contract with local farmers, the same as they would for their own food.  "We need 20 pigs, 100 chickens, 2 barrels of beer, and 2 wagonloads of hay." (Grocery list truncated)

Comment: @Cyn Problem here is that the list contains (probably) everything the farmer owns. Most farmers object to that. Enemy farmers for sure, allied farmers weren't very keen either.

Comment: @Jos And that's assuming the army even *asks* the farmers.  Or pays them.  Yeah, war is horrible for all sorts of reasons.  Ransacking the countryside for supplies and starving the people you're pretending to go to war to protect is part of it.  If the army does contract, it would be with a community of farmers (and others), not just one.

Comment: An army wouldn't contract with farmers. If it does anything close to being nice it will contract with the local lord or municipality if they're on the same side.

Comment: For some Armies for example the English during the Hundred Years War the act of raiding and pillaging the enemy countryside was an end in itself.

Answer (score 3):

If we want to know about war horses in the middle ages we can look at the nomads that visited Europe a prime example of which were the Mongols. In ["Horse and pasture in Inner Asian History"](http://oriens-extremus.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/OE-19-19.pdf) by Denis Sinor a case is described were the lack of edible grass hindered the Mongol advance.

> In March 1242, a Mongol detachment
>   pursuing the fleeing Hungarian king Bela IV reached the city of Split in
>   Dalmatia. The archdeacon Thomas of Split, describing the events, expressly
>   stated that Qaidan, chief of the Mongol forces engaged in the operations
>   arrived with only a fraction of his army "as there was not enough grass for
>   all his horsemen; it was early March with heavy frosts".

If war horses needed a special type of hay and did not graze then they would make sure to make provisions of it and wouldn't rely on local fauna.

Comment: The problem here is what the OP means by "war horses".  There's a big difference between Mongol horses - small, stocky, and adapted to steppe conditions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_horse ) and the large war horses bred to carry European knights in armor.

Comment: @jamesqf You are right mongol horses were different than european horses in their physiology, however I don't see why they should be different in their diet. European horses were kept in stables and fed hay true but as Jos said in his answer they are still horses. Grass is their friend.

Comment: It's not "European horses" in general, but specific breeds that have been bred, or evolved, to do certain things.  So if you take a mustang like mine, whose ancestors spent several centuries scrabbling for survival in the sagebrush steppe of the Great Basin, they're probably going to have a rather tougher digestion than say a pampered thorobred.  Just for instance, while we were out riding today, I noticed him eating (with apparent relish!) bitterbrush, rabbitbrush, yarrow, and the tops of a couple of small pine trees, among other things.

Comment: @jamesqf: *Thoroughbreds* are *Arabians*. Look it up, that what is *thorough* about their *breeding*. Nothing at all to do with the steeds used by medieval knights, which would be more akin to elite draft horses like Clydesdales or riding breeds like the Lipazzans.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: Thoroughbreds are NOT Arabians, but were developed by crossing English horses with Arab stallions, much later than horses that would have been ridden by knights.  They were, of course, bred primarily for racing.  (And in modern times, for distances not much more than a mile or so.)  Purebred Arabians are quite different, and tend to dominate in endurance racing.  I'll save you the trouble of looking it up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thoroughbred  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabian_horse

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: To avoid any nitpicks, I was thinking of US flat racing.  Britsh steeplechase racing (which I only know about via a few of Dick Francis' mysteries) apparently has course lengths from 2-6 miles.  That's still much different from the 25-100 miles typical of endurance racing.

Comment: @jamesqf: To be a thoroughbred, every male ancestor since the 17th century must be one of three Arabian stallions imported into England at that time. "*All modern Thoroughbreds can trace their pedigrees to three stallions originally imported into England in the 17th and 18th centuries, and to a larger number of foundation mares of mostly English breeding.*" That severely limits how far from *Arabian* their genetic profile can wander, and clearly marks them as, at least arguably, a sub-breed of Arabian.

Comment: Thoroughbreds are also bred to carry a total weight - saddle, rider, and tack - of around 10 stone / 140 pounds. Hard to find a knight in armour who could make that weight limit. Clearly a *light cavalry* horse, not a cuirassier's.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: And?  First, you're neglecting the female ancestors.  Second, if "every male ancestor since the 17th century must be one of three Arabian stallions...", then perhaps we should enquire as to why those stallions are so long-lived :-)  As I said, thoroughbreds were developed by crossing English horses with those Arabs.  That breeding started LONG after the days of knights in armor, and largely for the purposes of racing.  Thus the low weight - though both my Anglo-arab mare and my friend's T-bred/quarterhorse easily carry my ~15 stone.